# R: Pearson's chi-squared test with multinomial logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression, chi-squared, multinomial, model-fitting

I am running a multinomial logistic regression comparable to this:

```
library(nnet)
data(mtcars)
mod <- multinom(vs ~ cyl + mpg, data = mtcars)
summary(mod)
```

I would like to run a pearson's chi-squared test to examine the fit of my model, but I've been unable to find any examples on how to do this based on output from a multinominal logistic regression model. I hope anyone can help a beginner in logistic regression with this matter. 
Thanks!